# Perform a substring_index Query

Tags: mysql

in a Row in MySQL Database have a data example "I NEED HELP"... "ASK A QUESTION", how to use a MySQL `SUBSTRING_INDEX` to return first and end words: "I HELP"... "ASK QUESTION"?

Using `SUBSTRING_INDEX(column, ' ', 2)` returns "I NEED", "ASK A".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could substring index the first and last then `CONCAT` it.

```
SELECT *,CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`column`,' ',1),' ',SUBSTRING_INDEX(`column`,' ',-1)) `NewText` 
FROM `MyTable` b;
```

This will generate an additional Column with the first and last index based on your separator.

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thankkksss friend! It's ok!!